# sed - comment a matching line and x lines after it

Tags: sed, text-manipulation

I need help with using sed to comment a matching lines and 4 lines which follows it.
in a text file.

my text file is like this:

```
[myprocess-a]
property1=1
property2=2
property3=3
property4=4

[anotherprocess-b]
property1=gffgg
property3=gjdl
property2=red
property4=djfjf

[myprocess-b]
property1=1
property4=4
property2=2
property3=3
```

I want to prefix # to all the lines having text '[myprocess' and 4 lines that follows it
expected output:

```
#[myprocess-a]
#property1=1
#property2=2
#property3=3
#property4=4

[anotherprocess-b]
property1=gffgg
property3=gjdl
property2=red
property4=djfjf

#[myprocess-b]
#property1=1
#property4=4
#property2=2
#property3=3
```

Greatly appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this by applying a regular expression to a set of lines:

```
sed -e '/myprocess/,+4 s/^/#/'
```

This matches lines with 'myprocess' and the 4 lines after them. For those 4 lines it then inserts a '#' at the beginning of the line.

(I think this might be a GNU extension - it's not in any of the "sed one liner" cheatsheets I know)

Comment: `sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unexpected ','`  :-(

Comment: What version of see? Odds are it's either old or not got the gnu extensions.

Comment: sed 4.2.2. It's the Debian default so, yeah, probably missing GNU extensions

Comment: gnu documentation for this: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Range-Addresses.html

Comment: How does one do it for all the lines after a matching pattern?

Comment: Off the top of my head I think changing +4 to $ would do that.

Comment: the above sed command, comments out the pattern match line also. if i want to exclude the pattern match line, then what will be the sed command ?

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/\[myprocess/ { N;N;N;N; s/^/#/gm }' input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Using string [concatenation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Concatenation.html) and the *default action* in `awk`.

```
awk '/myprocess/{f=1} f>5{f=0} f{f++; $0="#" $0} 1'  foo.txt
```

Alternatively, if the block always ends with an empty line:

```
awk '/myprocess/{f=1} !NF{f=0} f{$0="#" $0} 1'  foo.txt
```